# What is plate glitching and how I can use it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What is the plate glitch in skyrim and what can I use it for? How and where can I use it? How can I use it to get through things as I have heard it can help me do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plate glitch is done by grabbing (not picking up) a plate, and lining yourself up with it and running at a wall. This can cause you to go through the wall. You can use it to go through a lot of walls, though Riften seems to be the best place to practice it. Some uses of it would be going through walls to avoid locked doors, or escaping the map to explore other areas. Corners of walls are sometimes easier than other parts of the wall.

Comment: Where are some locations that I can find hidden chests as I have heard you can do that? Do I sprint through the wall, can I use it to get through blocked entrances and what kind of walls can I get through

Comment: @Matthew_m321 you can go through pretty much any wall that is flat, and you can sprint, walk, or whirlwind sprint. pick whichever works best for you. As far as the location of hidden chests, that would probably be better in a separate question